# OpenCL ND-Range boundaries?

Tags: opencl, boundary

Consider a kernel which performs vector addition:

```
__kernel void vecAdd(__global double *a,
                     __global double *b,
                     __global double *c,
                     const unsigned int n)
{                                           
    //Get our global thread ID              
    int id = get_global_id(0);              

    //Make sure we do not go out of bounds  
    if (id < n)                             
        c[id] = a[id] + b[id];              
}
```

Is it really necessary to pass the size `n` to the function, and do a check on the boundaries ?

I have seen the same version without the check on `n`. Which one is correct?

More generally, I wonder what happens if the data size to process is different than the user defined NR-Range.

Will the remaining, out-of-bounds, data be processed or not?

- Is so, how is it processed ?
- If not, does that mean that the user have to consider boundaries when programming a Kernel ?

Does OpenCL specifies any of that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The check against n is a good idea if you aren't certain to have a multiple of n work items. When you know you will only ever call the kernel with n work items, the check is only taking up processing cycles, kernel size, and the instruction scheduler's attention.

Nothing will happen with the extra data you pass to the kernel. Although if you don't use the data at some point, you did waste time copying it to the device.

I like to make a kernel's work group and global size independent of the total work to be done. I need to pass in 'n' when this is the case.

For example:

```
__kernel void vecAdd(  __global double *a, __global double *b, __global double *c, const unsigned int n)
{                                           
    //Get our global thread ID and global size
    int gid = get_global_id(0);              
    int gsize = get_global_size(0);              

    //check vs n using for-loop condition
    for(int i=gid; i<n; i+= gsize){
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i];              
    }
}
```

The example will take an arbitrary value for n, as well as any global size. each work item will process every nth element, beginning at its own global id. The same idea works well with work groups too, sometimes outperforming the global version I have listed due to memory locality.

If you know the value of n to be constant, it is often better to hard code it (as a DEFINE at the top). This will let compilers optimize for that specific value and eliminate the extra parameter. Examples of such kernels include: DFT/FFT processing, bitonic sorting at a given stage, and image processing using constant dimensions.

Comment: `+1` A good answer, but I would advise against defining constants as macros. Prefer `static const` whenever possible.

Comment: True. Better still, 'reqd_work_group_size' serves the purpose well. https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/functionQualifiers.html

Comment: @mfa I'm not sure I understand the `for` loop: isn't `n` supposed to be smaller than `gsize`? Or does that mean you implicitly have a 2d ND-Range?

Comment: It means this kernel can process more elements than there are work-items.

Comment: Still 1D range. But like the other comment says: work items can process more than one output.

Comment: n is still the total length of your vectors in your example

Comment: @mfa thanks. One more question then: in this case, is `global_work_size` supposed to be the total length of the vector as well (`n == global_work_size`)?

Comment: No, those values are independent. It works as long as both n and global size are greater than zero.

Comment: @mfa ok, thank you. As far as I understand, if `n == global_work_size`, then you don't need the `n` parameter in the kernel signature. Otherwise, you can use the technique you have proposed.

Comment: @mfa I'm having much better results with the kernel in my original post than yours. I've tried with `n=100millions` and various `global_work_size`. The farthest the value is from the vector size `n`, the worse the results are.

Comment: That's good to hear. The best thing to do is benchmark your different options and see what works best on your hardware. What device are you testing on?

Comment: @mfa I'm using Tesla m1060. One thing I don't get about your kernel is that, won't this do a lot of over/unnecessary calculations for sizes of `global_work_size < n`? As the global id increments, it will be on indexes of the array that have already been computed by the previous kernels applied to previous indexes.

Comment: i increments by +gsize, so there is no overlap. the kernel I posted in your other question uses work groups for computing adjacent elements. This kernel was only an example of how to make global size not dependent on the value of n.

Comment: @mfa Say i have an array of 10 elements to process and set  `global_work_size=3`. Kernel applied to cell index `i=0` will process elements at indexes `0,3,6,9`. Kernel applied to cell index `i=1` will process elements at indexes `1,4,7`. Etc. What happens when kernel is applied to cell index `i=3`? Since it has already been processed by Kernel applied to cell index `i=0`.

Comment: @mfa having wrote my above comment i realize now that the grid is `global_work_size` length, so there indeed won't be overlaps :o I will look at your other kernel with WG to see if I have better performance. Still, the naive implementation gives the best results for now. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is typical when the host code specifies the workgroup size, because in OpenCL 1.x the global size must be a multiple of the work group size. So if your data size is 1000 and your workgroup size is 128 then the global size needs to be rounded up to 1024. Hence the check. In OpenCL 2.0 this requirement has been removed.